# Best way to implement loading screen in android

Tags: android, view

i am making lot of HTTP calls in my applications & switches between the views, now i'm handling the Http calls in a thread, but i want to make user to wait when the http request in progress. How to do this?. I just need to show a wait cursor or loading string.

Comment: use asynctask. but its not good to keep user waiting for a long time.

Comment: Hi raghu, thanks lot. But how to make user to wait. with help of wait dialog. any hint

Comment: you display a progressdialog in `onPreExecute` and dismiss in `onPostExecute`.

Comment: ah, ok you are right, Now i need to look on how to show progressdialog in android right. Thanks ill investigate, thanks lot

Comment: I did this, thanks lot. it worked :)

Comment: in my app around 10 different http apis are there, so each api is covered with one different asynctask. And in dobackground i'm performing the operation & also similarly i'm loading wait screen there. Is there any other optimized way you suggest? thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a ProgressDialog whit a Handler.

[Android Progress Dialog Example](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/android-app-builder/androids-indeterminate-progressdialog-tutorial/)

[Android's indeterminate ProgressDialog tutorial](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/android-app-builder/androids-indeterminate-progressdialog-tutorial/)

Cheers

Comment: in my app around 10 different http apis are there, so each api is covered with one different asynctask. And in dobackground i'm performing the operation & also similarly i'm loading wait screen there. Is there any other optimized way you suggest? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I find the name a bit misleading, but you should show a [ProgressBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) while background operations conclude.

Comment: Yes, but if i need to make user to wait in definitely as i dont no how long it takes response to come

Comment: You can set ProgressBar.indeterminate

Answer (score 0):

May be this will helpful. You have to make a background operation using thread concept like `AsyncTask`. Using this you can hide the actual work from the UI part. And AsyncTask will get unallocated after your operations are completed.

- Create a subclass of `AsyncTask`
- Use AsyncTask to do background work
- Call `onPreExecute()` to initialize task
- Use a progressbar with `setIndeterminate(true)` to enable the indeterminate mode
- Call `onProgressUpdate()` to animate your progressbar to let the user know some work is being done
- Use `incrementProgressBy(`) for increment progressbar content by a specific value
- Call `doInBackground()`and do the background work here
- Catch an `InterruptedException` object to find end of background operation
- Call `onPostExecute()` to denote the end of operation and show the result